# How to use SQLAlchemy addcolumn to include a func.count value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables,let's call them A and B.
A has some information about each user, and B has some services of users.
Here I want to use SQLAlchemy to query the user and count of their services.

```
--------
A:
username(primary key),
age,
full_name,
password
B:
username,
service_name
--------
```

I can use `session.query(A).filter(A.username.like('foo%'))` to query users,but I cannot add the sum column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more permanent way of attaching the count to the objects but this will let you get the count and the objects at the same time.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
query = session.query(A, func.count(B.service_name))
query = query.outerjoin(B, A.username == B.username)
query = query.group_by(A.username).filter(A.username.like('foo%'))
for (user, user_service_count) in query.all():
    print(user, user_service)
```

Comment: I written like this before, however, it cannot output the result that has count of zero but the expected result is A and number zero.For example, if foo_bar has no service in table B, it will not output foo_bar.

Comment: Just solved it! :) It should add `isouter=True` in the join, like `query = query.join(B, A.username == B.username, isouter=True)`

Comment: You're right, I fixed my answer.  I used `outerjoin()` though instead of the argument but same thing.